# Order ggplot legend differently than elements in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

Is there a way to order a legend in ggplot differently than the elements on the plot. for example I want the legend to be ordered Calanoida, Cladocera, Rotifera, and Cyclopoida but I want the ggplot to look the exact same with Calanoida on the bottom of the stacked bars and Cyclopoida on the top.

Thank you in advance. Also if you know how to add spaces in between bars on a stacked group barplot that would be helpful as well. I usually use

`geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 6))` but the position argument is being used as `geom_bar(position = "stack")` when making a stacked bar plot...

[image]

```
Zoop_df_Ab = structure(list(Type = c("Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton"), Analysis = c("Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance"), Lake = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("Lake N11", 
"Area 8", "East Lake", "Lake 3", "Lake D2/D3"), class = "factor"), 
    Season = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("July", "August", "September"
    ), class = "factor"), Class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("Cyclopoida", 
    "Rotifera", "Cladocera", "Calonoida"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(31.98162171, 36.39715076, 10.4136626, 12.06768565, 
    38.64860417, 3.742104317, 19.28343448, 51.39177662, 42.69303059, 
    10.89828073, 37.6923044, 30.19541624, 72.52209628, 76.49344251, 
    49.13209458, 34.6058036, 34.72740008, 86.59848507, 54.32721503, 
    56.46492886, 95.39481296, 50.91696935, 34.22043376, 44.75895084, 
    71.24798268, 47.33509161, 64.89139552, 11.5376884, 8.058506181, 
    42.18223086, 0.214567442, 0.858128087, 0.859215877, 1.016869217, 
    0.255412534, 0.254841312, 2.904754731, 1.33692291, 3.971509741, 
    5.106726241, 3.157013231, 0.874656528, 5.499848364, 0.833803688, 
    3.943039326, 33.19801615, 28.01733131, 2.128631466, 32.58822874, 
    4.631055299, 0.608235357, 26.89484164, 13.05085317, 8.576504648, 
    12.74700931, 11.81559686, 4.038527706, 10.44035937, 14.61425814, 
    4.742638092)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
Ab_plot_Zoop <- ggplot(Zoop_df_Ab,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
                        aes(x = Lake,
                            y = Value,
                            fill = Class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack", width = 0.6) +
  geom_vline(data = dat_vline, aes(xintercept = xintercept), lineend = "square") +
  geom_hline(data = dat_hline, aes(yintercept = yintercept), lineend = "square") +
  theme_classic() + theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
                          text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
  ) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance (%)"))) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(Season, levels=c('July','August','September')), strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") + theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
                                             plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.3, 0.3)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'lightgrey', 'white','darkgrey')) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "Class",
    values = c('none', 'none', 'crosshatch', 'stripe')
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(
    "Class",
    values = c(0,0, 30, 45)
  ) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = Class),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .02,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "black",
  )
Ab_plot_Zoop
```

Comment: Generally I recommend `factor`s for ordering things, not sure if what you're suggesting is possible. Please add sample data and code you're using to generate this.

Comment: factor will order the plot and legend

Comment: Yes, and that behavior is generally desired, though I recognize you're looking for a different order between the two.

Comment: Yes so legend ordered opposite direction of the plot. I added code to reproduce the plot. "Zoop_df$Class <- factor(Zoop_df$Class, levels=c("Cyclopoida", "Rotifera", "Cladocera", "Calonoida"))" orders both

Comment: Thank you confusedindividual for your edits, it provided the clarity I was looking for. I hope my answer comes close to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `breaks=`, you can change the order within a legend; this needs to be done for all scales shown in the legend, so it'll be done multiple times.

When doing work like this, I tend to use a `data.frame` that matches the `Class` values with its scale parameters, such as:

```r
classes <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Class      , ~fill      , ~pattern    , ~pattern_angle, ~order
  , "Calonoida" , "darkgrey" , "stripe"    ,             45,      1
  , "Cladocera" , "white"    , "crosshatch",             30,      2
  , "Rotifera"  , "lightgrey", "none"      ,              0,      3
  , "Cyclopoida", "black"    , "none"      ,              0,      4
)
```

The use of `tribble` is certainly not required to make this frame, I use it here because it shows everything lined up nicely. Also, I added the `order` column here because it was convenient to create this table elsewhere and sort into this final form.

The other thing I much prefer to do is to provide *named* values when using a `scale_*_manual`. That is, `c(0,0,30,45)` works fine until at some point you change the order of values in your `factor` for whatever reason and forget to change the order of these numbers. By using a named-vector, we guard against that silent corruption (in a sense).

I'm commenting out the `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` since I don't have those data.

This is your original code:

```r
ggplot(Zoop_df_Ab,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
       aes(x = Lake,
           y = Value,
           fill = Class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack", width = 0.6) +
  # geom_vline(data = dat_vline, aes(xintercept = xintercept), lineend = "square") +
  # geom_hline(data = dat_hline, aes(yintercept = yintercept), lineend = "square") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
        text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance (%)"))) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(Season, levels=c('July','August','September')), strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.3, 0.3)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('black', 'lightgrey', 'white','darkgrey')) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "Class",
    values = c('none', 'none', 'crosshatch', 'stripe')
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(
    "Class",
    values = c(0,0, 30, 45)
  ) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = Class),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .02,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "black",
    )
```

[image: original ggplot]

Here is the updated code with my changes:

```r
ggplot(Zoop_df_Ab,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
       aes(x = Lake,
           y = Value,
           fill = Class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack", width = 0.6) +
  # geom_vline(data = dat_vline, aes(xintercept = xintercept), lineend = "square") +
  # geom_hline(data = dat_hline, aes(yintercept = yintercept), lineend = "square") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
        text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance (%)"))) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(Season, levels=c('July','August','September')), strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.3, 0.3)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = setNames(classes$fill, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "Class",
    values = setNames(classes$pattern, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(
    "Class",
    values = setNames(classes$pattern_angle, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = Class),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .02,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "black",
    )
```

[image: updated ggplot]